# Getting undefined prop in functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am having a weird issue when attempting to get the value of props in React Native.

I have the following App.js

```
export default function App(props) {
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
  console.log(`props: ${props.studentList}`);// props: [{"name":"John","course":"Javascript"},{"name":"Jane","course":"ReactNative"}]
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home Screen">
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home Screen"
          component={HomeScreen}
          initialParams={{studentList: props.studentList}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Screen One"
          component={ScreenOne}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Which is going to the default route `HomeScreen`:

HomeScreen.java:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Pressable} from 'react-native';

export default function HomeScreen({navigation, route}) {
  const {studentList} = route.params;
  console.log(`studentList: ${studentList}`); //studentList[{"name":"John","course":"Javascript"},{"name":"Jane","course":"ReactNative"}]
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.titleText}>Home Screen</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <Pressable
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Screen One', students)}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}> Go to Screen One</Text>
        </Pressable>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

The HomeScreen exposes a button to pass a list of students in ScreenOne. Until here so far so good.

ScreenOne.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Pressable} from 'react-native';
import Student from '../components/Student';

export default function ScreenOne(props) {
  const students = props.route.params;
  console.log(`students: ${students}`); // students [{"name":"John","course":"Javascript"},{"name":"Jane","course":"ReactNative"}]
  return students?.map((student) => {
    console.log(`student: ${student}`); //student: {"name":"John","course":"Javascript"}
    return <Student student={student} />;
  });
}
```

Student component receives the information of each student and **it is in here where I receive undefined value**:
Student.js:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

export default function Student({student}) {
  console.log(`student: ${student}`); //student: {"name":"John","course":"Javascript"}
  console.log(`student.name: ${student.name}`); //undefined
  console.log(`student.course: ${student.course}`); //undefined
  const {name, course} = student;
  console.log(name);
  console.log(course);
  
}
```

Do you know what is the issue in here?

Thanks

Comment: Is `Student` rendered multiple times?

Comment: Hi @RobinThomas Just one time

Comment: And `student` is of `object` type (`console.log(typeof student);`), and not some JSON string?

Comment: check student is a json object `console.warn(typeof student)` and use optional chaining just incase theres an issue where the component is rendering before it receives the data or thedata is malformed for some reason `student?.name`

Comment: @RobinThomas `student` is a `string`

Comment: Thanks @RobinThomas Why in here ` return students?.map((student) => {`, students is type of object and the student is type of string. How could I ensure to be type object as well?

Comment: @JohnBarton Because `students` is an array of `string`s. I don't know how you generate the `students` array, but your issue is from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that `student` is not an object and instead its a JSON string. Which is why you are getting `undefined` since both `name` and `course` properties do not exist on this string.

What you need to do is to convert this JSON string to an object by using `JSON.parse` (after which, both `name` and `course` will exist):

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

export default function Student({student}) {
  console.log(`student: ${student}`); //student: {"name":"John","course":"Javascript"}

  const { name, course } = JSON.parse(student);
}
```

> The JSON.parse() static method parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string. An optional reviver function can be provided to perform a transformation on the resulting object before it is returned.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse